# Are there any way to redirect the page when URL is provided in address bar in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a View called `Reports`, under that I have 2 different Views called `Races` and `Sire`. I am calling these 2 Views as partial views inside `Reports` page.

When user type `http://localhost:53987/Reports/Reports#` in the address bar, it loads `Races` and `Sire` which are main views, as partials inside `Reports`. But What I want is that when user put `http://localhost:53987/Races/Races#` in the address bar, it should redirect this to `http://localhost:53987/Reports/Reports#`.

Can anyone please suggest me how to acheive this.

`Reports` View

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Race">Race</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#sire">Sire</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="race" class="tab-pane fade">
                @Html.Partial("~/Views/Racing/Race.cshtml", Model.clsRace)
            </div>
            <div id="sire" class="tab-pane fade">
                @Html.Partial("~/Views/Sire/Sire.cshtml", Model.clsSire)
            </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: You can define a route definition for `url: Races/Races` that sets the defaults as `Reports` method in `ReportsController` But why do you have a method for it if you do not want users to navigate to it?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Thank you for your comment. Can you please elaborate more so that I will try to implement it. Basically,I had developed 2 different controllers called `Race` and `Sire` previously and all the related partials. Now I have created `Reports` controller where I have called these 2 Views as partials.

Comment: You do not need controller methods to render partials using `@Html.Partial(...)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I have done something like this `@Html.Partial("~/Views/Racing/Race.cshtml", Model.clsRace)`. Even though, there is controller and View called `Race`. When user types `http://localhost:53987/Races/Races#` in address bar then it should redirect to `http://localhost:53987/Reports/Reports#`. Can you please explain more so that I will try to implement it. Thank you for your help as always.

Comment: Just delete the controller methods - they are not required - the user will then get a 404 if they try to navigate to it (again - why are you creating controller methods for thing that you do not want the user to navigate to)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, those controllers method I had created long back when I had no View called `Reports`. You are right Stephen. Those Controller method is not required now. I commented those part and now I am getting 404 error if I navigate to this page. But just for my curosity, are there any way where I can forcefully navigate to another page.

Comment: Read my first comment

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I got it now. Thank you Stephen. Can you please provide answer for this. I am eager to accept your answer. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you are doing is rendering those partials using `@Html.Partial()`, then your controller methods are not necessary and you can just delete them (the user would get a `404: Not Found` if they try to navigate to those urls).

If however, you were using `@Html.Action()` to render them (because you had to execute some code in the controller to generate the partial), then the methods should be marked with the `[ChildActionOnly]` attribute (which prevents the user navigating to them.

If you did want to allow a user to enter those url's in the address bar, but redirect to `../Reports/Reports`, then you could create a specific route definitions for them, for example

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Races",
    url: "Races/Races",
    defaults: new { controller = "Report", action = "Report" }
);
```

and locate them before any other matching routes.

Comment: You are genius. For any doubt, you have answers for that. Thank you.